# Split huge PNG image file with ImageMagick

Tags: image, split, imagemagick, png, crop

I have huge image PNG file screenshot with scroll of dimensions 1280x99835 pixels. I want to split this file into tiles of 1783 pixels height.

Tried with ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16 on Windows 10 with 32 GB of ram with command:

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick.exe" convert out7.png -verbose -crop 1280x1783 tiles%03d.png
```

This is producing only 11 files ( should be 55 files ) and stops around 19613 pixels of height ( file is 99835 pixels ), there is no error:

`out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[0] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+0 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 1.109u 0:00.456
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[1] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+1783 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 1.578u 0:00.658
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[2] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+3566 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 2.109u 0:00.854
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[3] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+5349 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 2.609u 0:01.059
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[4] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+7132 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 3.047u 0:01.252
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[5] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+8915 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 3.469u 0:01.494
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[6] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+10698 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 3.938u 0:01.734
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[7] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+12481 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 4.219u 0:01.955
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[8] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+14264 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 4.672u 0:02.190
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[9] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+16047 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 4.984u 0:02.415
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[10] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x1783 1280x19196+0+17830 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 5.516u 0:02.674`

If I increase crop height it produces less files but stops around same height:

`out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[0] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x3566 1280x19196+0+0 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 1.281u 0:00.616
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[1] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x3566 1280x19196+0+3566 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 2.031u 0:01.020
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[2] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x3566 1280x19196+0+7132 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 2.781u 0:01.461
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[3] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x3566 1280x19196+0+10698 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 3.453u 0:01.892
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[4] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x3566 1280x19196+0+14264 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 4.156u 0:02.337
out7.png=>tiles%03d.png[5] PNG 1280x99835=>1280x3566 1280x19196+0+17830 8-bit sRGB 29.579MiB 4.891u 0:02.828`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to split whole file?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `+repage` after `out7.png` Your image has *"remembered"* it used to be 1280x19196 in a previous life.

Comment: That helped! I added that +repage before but it didn't hel, maybe it was in wrong place of command? What this +repage actually does?

Comment: It makes the image forget its virtual canvas, which it remembers according to where it originated from. If you don't understand it or want it, it is probably best to always repage after cutting, cropping, tiling or trimming. It can be useful, say in an animation where you might have a big bear filling most of the frame and just its arm moving - you can just redraw the moved arm without having to redraw the entire bear, because the arm extract can remember where it belongs on the canvas.